# Using react-sortable-hoc with react-virtualized Grid

Tags: react-virtualized, react-sortable-hoc

I want to use [react-sortable-hoc](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc) with [react-virtualized's Grid](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/Grid) where the rows are sortable. I cannot use the [List](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List) as I have multiple columns and I cannot use it with the [Table](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/Table) because I have too many columns and therefore need horizontal scrolling.

The issue that I am facing is that the Grid does not have a `rowRenderer` callback as the Table or List has (it only has [`cellRenderer`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Grid.md#cellrenderer) and [`cellRenderer`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Grid.md#cellrangerenderer)), thus I don't know what to wrap the `SortableElement` around.

I would appreciate any ideas or examples of this usage?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up implementing this as a cellRangeRenderer - see my comment on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/issues/295#issuecomment-344070823

Comment: Thanks for sharing your `rowCellRangeRenderer` implementation. Can you also share how you tie it all together? How do you integrate `Grid` with `SortableContainer`, `SortableElement`?