# Sortable rows using react-sortable-hoc and react-virtualized's MultiGrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized, react-sortable-hoc

I've been trying to make the react-virtualized's MultiGrid sortable. In the end, I adjusted the MultiGrid's Grids to get my desired effect. However, when sorting, the rows don't transition properly and always move to the extremes (topmost or bottom most). Heres a codesandbox demo of what I've made so far: https://codesandbox.io/s/5kl4z8olrn

### I need help fixing the row transitions and for it to sort correctly.

Before someone links some useless examples, I've searched and I haven't found anything that actually show the react-sortable-hoc components. The closest solution was on [Using react-sortable-hoc with react-virtualized Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46847633/using-react-sortable-hoc-with-react-virtualized-grid?rq=1) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Styles were needed for the rows to properly sort and transition.